# Javascript: Hide div progressBar on 2nd page

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a survey, so when the user selects 'no' on the first page, it takes them to the 2nd page that says 'Thanks for your time'. If they select 'yes', it moves forward with the survey. There is a progress bar on every page, but I don't want it to show on the 2nd page because it's a 'thank you' page. I didn't write any of the original code, this project is just being handed to me to get rid of the progress bar. I don't have much JS experience so please don't eat me alive.

Here is the code I've tried so far and other similar derivatives of that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var curPage = parseInt($('input[name=currentpage]').val(), 10);
    if (curPage == 2) {
        $('progressBar').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: The selector `$('progressBar')` does not select anything.  Is `progressBar` supposed to be a class or an id?

Comment: Is `progressBar` an id for an element? If so, use `#progressBar` instead of `progressBar` in selector.

Comment: I don't even have access to the html... I am only inspecting the page at this point

<div class="progressBar springgreen">
 <ul>

So it's a class, yes

Comment: Since its a class then you should include a dot as follows: .progressBar so the full line would be $('.progressBar').hide();

Comment: Thanks Sarah for the suggestion! I added that in and nothing changed. I also saw something online that was like $('.progressBar').first().hide(); but that also did nothing... :\

Comment: no probs @Alyssa. Do you have access to the original JS files? There could be a few reasons why its not working: Maybe the progressBar is being shown after you're hiding it in the JS code.. Is curPage returning the right value for each page? you can check this by logging it to the console. console.log(curPage); its probably better if you find the original code thats showing the progress Bar and put an if statement there to check which page it is and then dont show it if it is the "thank you" page.